# Twitter Badge on my website

Tags: html, twitter

Hey. Problem with my request is that this website doesn't work with javascript, so i need some kind of embed code, or some alternate to do it. I know it is possible, i just don't know how.
I want it to look like Twitter's Twitter Badge thingie, only without the real scripts.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure what you are asking here ..

Comment: Please give an example of what you're referring to. If you're talking about the embedded Twitter widgets, your choices are to use Javascript and do it server-side. The latter case is an entire different question entirely. http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you need?:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">
<img src="http://a0.twimg.com/a/1288470193/images/fronts/logo_withbird_home.png" alt="" />
</a>
```